# Windows Server 2K3, Domain Controller Update Error Code: 0x80070005

Tags: windows, update

I had several Server Win2K3 machines with the same error. On all but one, the reset.cmd fixed the issue. The one it failed on is a DC and the primary. Any ideas on how to get around this failure? I'm guessing it's because it's a DC. Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 0):

That error number is often a permission denied error. Disable all anti-virus on the server before updating again. If the problem persists, you may have to turn [security auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771395%28WS.10%29.aspx) on and then parse the security logs for any failure audits that apply to when you try and retrieve updates.

Another possibility is to run the Genuine Advantage Diagnostic Tool and then retry the update service. It's within the realm of possibility that there is some kind of genuineness issue that is causing the update service to malfunction.

**EDIT:**

Some more tricks:

- [Rename the SoftwareDistribution folder](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverManagement/thread/88e68d26-30a6-4dde-993b-9402cae82ec8/) and then try updates again.
- Download and install the update manually. Sometimes, even if it doesn't install correctly that way, you can get a different error code with more information.
- Make sure you're running the latest Windows Update agent: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946928
- Scorch the very earth the server sits on: [Revert to default permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222). I completely renounce all responsibility for this action. You might do this as a last effort before re-installing the DC. =)

Comment: Did all you suggested. Passed Genuine Advantage Diagnostic. No AV running and no issues so far in Security Auditing. And still can't install this latest update Update for Windows Server 2003 (KB2607712). Same error as before. I can't figure why a third of my servers would suddnly develope this, and all can be fixed except the DC> Thanks, Joe

Comment: @Joseph I updated my answer.